# Extract unique information from master sheet with a specified value in a given range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a master sheet with thousands of rows. This sheet is basically the mother sheet where other sheets will be taking their data from. Let's take the following mother table for example:

[image: Mother Sheet]

Now I have another sheet which is exclusively for musical events. The table looks like this:

[image: Musical Sheet]

Basically, what I need is a formula in A3, that will extract only unique musical events from the mother sheet.

I know this can be achieved using a pivot table, but I prefer the formula method, which would probably involve index and match.

Thank you.

Comment: Will there be duplicate rows in your master sheet? i.e., "Musical|123|456|789" could appear more than once?

Comment: Basically, in the second sheet, A3 and onward will extract only unique names from the mother sheet, and then the location (B3 and onward) and time (C3 and onward) will get their values based on the name using a simple index match formula.

Comment: So to answer your question, it doesn't matter if location and time contains duplicates as the name contains only unique values.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 1):

You can fill all three columns with one formula.

This array formula in A3 of your second sheet must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  If done correctly, the formula will be surrounded by curly braces in the formula bar.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(IF($A$1:$A$10="Musical",B$1:B$10,""),SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$10="Musical",ROW(B$1:B$10),""),ROW()-2)),"")`

You will also have to modify the ranges to include the name of your master sheet, i.e., `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10`, and expand the ranges as necessary.  Since your master table has thousands of rows, you could use whole column ranges, i.e. `Sheet1!$A:$A`.

After the formula is entered in A3, fill it to the right, and then down until the results show as blank.  Here is a sample table where the original and new values are on the same sheet.

[image]

Note: IFERROR() can be somewhat slow, so you may want to fill down in steps and wait for the results to appear each time.

Good luck, and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but will this only extract unique values for name and ignore this condition for location and time?

Comment: Like what if you have two musical events under the name of ABC, will it return two ABC or just one for the event name?

Comment: I need to add a condition to check if the value in column A of sheet 2 already exists in previous A cells of sheet 2, and if it does, it will skip it and proceed to the next one.

Comment: Everywhere there is "Musical" in column A, it will return the corresponding values in columns B, C and D. That's why I asked you if there were duplicates. You said it didn't matter because the names are unique. If that's true, there won't be any duplicate events.

Comment: Yeah, there are duplicates actually. I apologize for not explaining myself properly.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on this again tomorrow.

Comment: Here's a first pass at creating the list of unique names. I won't be able to test this until tomorrow.  In A3 of the second sheet: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,Sheet1!A:A),0))`

Comment: Hello there. Firstly, I would like to thank you a lot for taking the time to help me out. Secondly, I have used the formula you've given me and it works great, but it has two major problems that renders it impossible for me to use it. The first problem is that the more you use the formula, the more slow and unresponsive your database becomes. I have used it on 10k+ cells and oh my god, the database was so slow to the point I had to hit my head against the wall

Comment: The second problem is that you can't filter data at all using this formula because it takes data in the exact same order as the mother sheet. Hence this formula is neither efficient nor effective.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help you out.